# Determine probability of specific outcome in R for Tree Model

Tags: r

How would I find the the probability of getting an outcome of Y=0 given new.data (X1=4,X2=4,X3=4) for a tree model I created with method = 'poisson'? Exact code below:

```
tree.pois.cp<-rpart(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = data, method = 'poisson', control = rpart.control(cp = 1.1034e-02))
```

I used the below code for the same thing but using my negative binomial model:

```
pred.y.nb<-predict(nb, newdata = new.data, type = "response")
prob0.nb<-dnbinom(0, mu=pred.y.nb, size=nb$theta)
prob0.nb
#this is my answer for probability of Y=0 given my negative binom model
```

(Shout out to this question for helping me out: [How to calculate the predicted probability of negative binomial regression model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213315/how-to-calculate-the-predicted-probability-of-negative-binomial-regression-model))

I tried using the same code for my tree model tree.pois.cp:

```
pred.y.pois.cp<-predict(tree.pois.cp, newdata = new.data, type = "response")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' should be one of “vector”, “prob”, “class”, “matrix”
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Please read `rpart` documentation. There is no `type = "response"` for predict `rpart` object. You can try below code:

```
data<-data.frame(Y=as.character(rpois(n = 20000,.2)),X1=sample(1:4,20000,replace = T),X2=sample(1:4,20000,replace = T),X3=sample(1:4,20000,replace = T),X4=sample(1:4,20000,replace = T))

tree.pois.cp<-rpart(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = data, method = 'class')
new.data<- data.frame(Y="0",X1=4,X2=4,X3=4,X4=4)
pred.y.pois<-predict(tree.pois.cp, newdata = new.data, type = "prob")
pred.y.pois
```